JSchException: Auth fail for methods 'publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password' - in Spring boot Native application with Apache Camel for SFTP
I am using below versions for spring boot native application
Java 17, Spring Boot 3.3.1, Graalvm 22.3.3. The same code or route with sftp is working fine with Spring Boot Maven Jar. i.e., SFTP credentials are correct.
I get this error only with Spring Boot "Native" Jar created with Graalvm Java using below command
./mvnw clean -Pnative native:compile


Java used is openjdk version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.3 (build 17.0.8+7-jvmci-22.3-b22)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.3.3 (build 17.0.8+7-jvmci-22.3-b22, mixed mode, sharing)

I am getting below error with "Spring boot Native" application using "Apache Camel for SFTP" with below route details and with below classes in src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json

com.jcraft.jsch.jce.HMACSHA1
com.jcraft.jsch.jce.Random
com.jcraft.jsch.jce.AES128CTR
com.jcraft.jsch.DHEC256
com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SHA256
com.jcraft.jsch.jce.ECDHN
com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureRSASHA512
com.jcraft.jsch.jce.HMACSHA256ETM
com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthNone

how to resolve the issue?
Route:
from("file:/home/temp/test/src").routeId("Encrypted Route")
.log ("Start: ${headers.CamelFileName}: ${headers.CamelFileLength} bytes")  
.to("sftp://testuser@testserver.amd.com/home/temp/test/src?password=RAW(XXXXXXXX)")
.log ("End: ${headers.CamelFileName}, ${headers.CamelFileLength} bytes ");

Exception stacktrace:
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://testuser@testserver.amd.com:22
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:139)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.connectIfNecessary(RemoteFileProducer.java:184)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.preWriteCheck(RemoteFileProducer.java:133)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:116)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.process(RemoteFileProducer.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:65)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.lambda$process$2(SendProcessor.java:239)
        at org.apache.camel.support.cache.DefaultProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(DefaultProducerCache.java:281)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:238)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.handleFirst(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:462)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:438)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.doRun(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:199)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.executeReactiveWork(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:189)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.tryExecuteReactiveWork(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:166)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:163)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.processNonTransacted(CamelInternalProcessor.java:355)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:331)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:491)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:244)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:205)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:204)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:118)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail for methods 'publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password'
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:520)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.tryConnect(SftpOperations.java:162)
        at org.apache.camel.support.task.BlockingTask.lambda$run$0(BlockingTask.java:40)
        at org.apache.camel.support.task.ForegroundTask.run(ForegroundTask.java:94)
        at org.apache.camel.support.task.BlockingTask.run(BlockingTask.java:40)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:137)
        ... 31 common frames omitted


Did you try to set preferredAuthentications=password via the query parameter?

I updated to destination using preferredAuthentications as shown below sftp://testuser@testserver.amd.com/home/temp/test/src?password=RAW(XXXXXXXX)&passiveMode=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&binary=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&reconnectDelay=10000&tempFileName=${headers.CamelFileName}.tmp&preferredAuthentications=password
Still got same error - Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail for methods 'publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password'
